# How to create datepicker showing startdate and enddate?

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I want to create jquery UI datepicker, from start to endDate. Unfortunately, part of this code doesn't work. Yet I troubleshot it and found no error. Is there anyway to improve my code to make this work? Jfiddle.net has been used on this code but I don't get any errors then.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">



 <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
   <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control" placeholder="enddate"/>
     </div>
  </div><br>
<br>
  <br/>
  <br/>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://raw.githack.com/jamiebicknell/Toggle-Switch/master/jquery.toggleswitch.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   // date functionality
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
   dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"

    });
  });
```

Comment: Why are you including two different versions of Bootstrap CSS? And it seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gt1w35cn/

Comment: @j08691, what did i do there, that was incorrect for DOM not to respond?

Comment: I dont seem to understand, the code is the same and yet to me it does not work. try use jsfiddle.net. i am still getting no where. try to clear catche browser.  i am using thingspeak channel.

Comment: I have also tried to use Notepadd++ local and run using Mozilla Browser, the datepicker seem to work as per Jsfiddle. But my application on thingspeak is not, same code. What could be the issue here? How do i fix it this? Please help mates, im stuck to this

Comment: Hi mates i end up figure it out, i end up redo just the HTML part, some other tag attributes were missing. so my DOM was unable to load the datepicker well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use jquery ui datepicker:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 

  <div >
     <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="from" placeholder="startdate"/>
  </div>
  

<!-- <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p> -->
 
 
</body>
</html>
```